# Arquillian and Persistence Context Integration

Tags: java, gradle, jakarta-ee, mocking, jboss-arquillian

Hi guys does any one face a simular problem ?
I work in gradle and I'm trying to make @PresistanceContext Work with Arquilian but I'm getting NullPointer Excepion.
I'm using weld as my container. 
The general idea is to have something like this.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyRemoteServiceTest {

@Rule
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

private static final String sampleData = "This is data";
private Data expectedData = new Data();


@PersistenceContext(unitName = "mydatabase")
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Inject
private MyRemoteServiceImpl myRemoteService;

@Mock
private OuterService outerService;

@Deployment
public static WebArchive deploy() {
    WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addClass(Data.class)
            .addClass(MyRemoteServiceImpl.class)
            .addClass(OuterService.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    return war;
}

@Before
public void setUp() {

    expectedData.setId(1);
    expectedData.setDesc("OuterServiceResponse");
    expectedData.setData(sampleData);
    String outerServiceResponse = "OuterServiceResponse";
    myRemoteService.setOuterService(outerService);
    when(outerService.getDesc()).thenReturn(outerServiceResponse);
}

@Test
public void testSave() {
    myRemoteService.addData(sampleData);
    Data found = myRemoteService.findOne(1);
    String testFound = found.getData();
    assertThat(testFound, containsString(expectedData.getData()));

}
```

OuterService is a simulation of something that I don't want to test.
I don't have much experience so I will be grateful for any new hits.